# jQuery get the tager from event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Hexagon.js and I need to get the .html() of the caller. If i do something like event.target and start moving with the slider, as long as the cursor is on the slider it works just fine, but if i move the cursor somewhere else (and still holding the slider, just like any other, dragging it with cursor and moving outisde of the slider box), I will get the data of that element I am currently hovering above. I need just the data of the caller, not form enyone else.

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
  slider = new hx.Slider(this, {max:100});

  slider.on('change', function(value){
    var target = $( event.target );
    console.log(target);
  });
});
```

Thanks for any hep.

Comment: `slider.on('change', function(value){
    var target = $( event.target );
    console.log(target);
  });` Just change the value param name to event. `function(event){......}`

Comment: @GhostFlyTiger Unfortunatelly this does not help

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html it's a little bit hard to answer but well, [according to docs](https://hexagonjs.io/docs/slider/) you have to initialize the slider with an html element and, you do.

```
new hx.Slider(this, {max:100});
```

`this` in this line is the html element, so you could just use it.

Now the problem is that since you use `function () {...}` syntax, each function has its own `this`.

You may either use arrow function (they don't have their own `this`) as `.on(...)` callback (if it works ok, because sometimes it doesn't with JQuery) or save current this in a variable.

```
$(".slider").each(function(){

  const slide = this;

  const slider = new hx.Slider(
     slide,
     {max:100}
   );

  slider.on('change', function(value){
    console.log(slide, `is html element!`);
    console.log(value, `is the value that has just changed!`);
  });

});
```